# Sending json post from xcode to wep.api

Tags: json, xcode4.6

I'm having troubles sending a post message to my Wep.api application. I already tried my wep.api on google chrome postman application and it works perfectly. I want my code in the xcode to send this json message to my wep.api

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{ UserName: "fjkdlajfka", DeviceID: "1568948" , Password: "fkjdalfda"}
```

But everytime i send the message, I keep getting null on the parameters. this is my xcode message:

```
NSString *JsonMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{UserName: \"%@\",DeviceID: \"%@\",Password: \"%@\"}",
                     Username.text,@"123456789",Password.text];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://192.168.xxx.xxxx:53913/api/LogIn"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [JsonMsg length]];

[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[theRequest setValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[JsonMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

if ( conn ) {
    webData = [NSMutableData data];

}
else {
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

Does anyone know whats the error here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid , you are missing quotes

```
NSString *JsonMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{"UserName": \"%@\",
                                                  "DeviceID": \"%@\",
                                                  "Password": \"%@\"}",
                     Username.text,@"123456789",Password.text];
```